# How to make it so i can pass a pointer of a class to another class which was declared from the first class

Tags: c++, class

Im working on a simple game engine, At the moment i have a class that just contains the whole game, and in this class i declare other classes (ex. Window, ErrorManager, etc.). Now the thing is that i want to access an instance from another instance, so for example i want to access the ErrorManager instance declared in the game class from the Window instance still declared in the game class.

My first idea was to make it so when the game was created you had to pass in a pointer to its instance, and then that instance pointer would be passed to all classes that needed to mess with instances inside the game class, Thing is that i cant do this because i would have to include the Game class in the Window class but that would create an include loop and the compiler just spits out an error at me.

Is there any way to accomplish what i thought would be the solution or is there a better overall way to approach this?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. When your question is about some code it is best to provide a [mcve], no matter how simple it is and how obvious it might appear to you. Code is so much simpler to read and understand than a description of code

Comment: In this case learn about dependency inversion. First declare abstract baseclasses (interfaces) and put those in seperate header file. Now both the using and the implementing class can be compiled using those interfaces. As a bonus learn about dependency injection and unit testing too (very important for bigger projects)

Comment: Also make sure the core of your game is free of any UI code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a forward declaration to break the loop.

Managed.h

```cpp
#ifndef MANAGED_H
#define MANAGED_H
class manager;  // forward declaration. An announcement that this type 
                // exists, but will be defined elsewhere.
class managed
{
    manager * mgr; // A pointer just needs to know the type it points at exists. 
                   // It does not need to know size or make-up of the type.
    managed(manager * mgr) : mgr(mgr)
    {
    }
};

#endif
```

Manager.h

```cpp
#ifndef MANAGER_H
#define MANAGER_H
#include "Managed.h"
class manager
{
    managed mgd;
    manager(): mgd(this) // note: Slightly dodgy managed::managed must NOT do 
                         // anything other than store this because this hasn't 
                         // been fully constructed yet
    {
    } 
};

#endif
```

Managed.cpp

```cpp
#include "managed.h"
#include "manager.h"

// can safely include and use public portions of manager here
```

Side note: I generally do not like these self-referential structures. You have to manage lifetimes very, very carefully.

Comment: With dependency inversion/injection life cycle management becomes more explicit and controllable. E.g. you can create instances in main and you will have very fine control over the lifetime of the objects.  What you absolutely don't want is global variables.